# Firebase - Retrieve property value by key

Tags: angular, firebase

E.g. - if referralId = `1OOdbg7u`, how would I retrieve the value 0 from the database.

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
  // referralId = 1OOdbg7u

  getNoOfReferredUsers(referralId) {
    if (referralId) {
      return this.afs.collection('waitlist', ref => ref.where(referralId, '>=', 0)).valueChanges();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think this can be acomplish with GraphQL and Apollo. github.com/arjunyel/firestore-apollo-graphql . There are several tutorials out there. Haven't tried it but that's the purpose fo graphql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firestore there is no way of returning just a single field of a document. You have to retrieve the entire document, and then you can find the referralId.
Like this:

```
getNoOfReferredUsers(referralId) {
  if (referralId) {
    return this.afs.collection('counters').doc('waitlist').valueChanges()
      .pipe(map(referrals => referrals[referralId]));
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this can be acomplish with GraphQL and Apollo. https://github.com/arjunyel/firestore-apollo-graphql